# ERROR Error: NG0502 with Angular Material ang tag <p>

Tags: angular, angular-material

Following the guide of Angular Material, I would like to put this code in my form.
But an error appears:

```
ERROR Error: NG0502: During hydration Angular was unable to locate a node using the 
"firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild" path, starting from the 
<mat-checkbox _ngcontent-ng-c2212856583="" value="pepperoni" class="mat-mdc-checkbox" 
ng-reflect-value="pepperoni" id="mat-mdc-checkbox-1">…</mat-checkbox> node.
```

When I remove the tag `<p>`, the error does not appear and my form body renders fine.

```html
 <section class="example-section">
    <h4>Select your toppings:</h4>
    <p><mat-checkbox (change)="addValue($event)" value="pepperoni" >Pepperoni</mat-checkbox></p>
    <p><mat-checkbox (change)="addValue($event)" value="extracheese" >Extra Cheese</mat-checkbox></p>
    <p><mat-checkbox (change)="addValue($event)" value="mushroom" >Mushroom</mat-checkbox></p>
  </section>
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

As mentioned, only removing tag `<p>` solves the problem. I would like other solutions or explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the examples and they have `formControlName` for reactive forms and `[(ngModel)]` for template driven forms. Your code doesn't have any of them. It might be the issue.

Comment: Tharks for the answer. But it's not the problem. I did the same scenario without use <mat-checkbox> and works fine (using the default checkbox html). The error when I use <mat-checkbox> only appear if the tag <p> is used  together.

Comment: Yeah. Wierd behaviour. At least knowing that error appears only with <p> mean that removing it is the simplest solution. So I think the problem is solved :)
I can add that such a problem may also be solved by updating andular and angular-material versions.

Comment: I found the solution (and the problem)... I just removed the provideClientHydration() from providers in app.config.ts file.

Comment: Oh, it is quite interesting. Do you use server-side rendering(SSR) in your app?